# indexOf doesn't find an existing value

Tags: javascript, indexof

I wonder why indexOf is not working (Google script). For example indexOf sends -1 for ffreak@gmx.at, which is stored in the variable email. I tested with indeOf("ffreak@gmx.at") (without variable) and it runs properly! It seems, that the value inside the variable is compromitted.
Any idea how to find out the problem?
Thanks in advance!

```
function getGutscheinCode(email) {

// Hier die Logik zum prüfen der Email einbauen
Logger.log("getGutscheinCode: >" + email + "<");    // see log below

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
var ws = ss.getSheetByName("data");

var ssEmail = ws.getRange(1,1,ws.getLastRow(),8).getValues();
var emailList = ssEmail.map(function (r){ return r[0]; });          // Email
var codList = ssEmail.map(function (r){ return r[4]; });            // Gutscheincode
var gutList = ssEmail.map(function (r){ return r[7]; });            // Gutscheincode eingelöst
ssEmail.map(function (r){ Logger.log(">"+ r[0] + "<") });           // see log below

var position = emailList.indexOf(email);                            // Seeking for the email
Logger.log(position);

if (position === -1) { 
    return 0;                                                       // Email nicht gefunden, kein Code vorhanden
  } else{ 
    if (gutList[position] == "Ja") {                                // Email vorhanden aber Gutschein bereits eingelöst
      return 0;
    } else {
      return codList[position];                                     // Email vorhanden und Gutschein nicht eingelöst
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
Logger.log:
03.03.2021, 12:00:43    Info    getGutscheinCode: >ffreak@gmx.at<
03.03.2021, 12:00:43    Info    >Email<
03.03.2021, 12:00:43    Info    ><
03.03.2021, 12:00:43    Info    >ff@gmx.at<
03.03.2021, 12:00:43    Info    >ffreak@gmx.at<
03.03.2021, 12:00:43    Info    -1.0
```

Comment: Why don't you log out contents of `emailList` instead of `ssEmail` to see what's really in there.

Comment: thx! For sure another possibility.

Comment: It seems, var ssEmail = ws.getRange(1,1,ws.getLastRow(),7).getValues(); sends no multidimensional array. Just an one-dimension array.   **confused**

Answer (score -1):

As you can see everything is working just fine if `ssEmail` got an array like that i posted. Check your `ssEmail` and other should be fine..

[image]

Comment: Thx a lot for now; i will checkt it.

Comment: You're right. I get only a one-dimension array. The question is why? getrange should deliver an multidimensional array, i thought.

Comment: I know it's a little stupid question, but are you sure you typed `getValues` instead of `getValue`, as `getValue` returns one dimensional array, while `getValues` gets two dimensional array

Comment: Questions are never stupid. But, ... yes, i used getValues.  Well. im using a workaround now, so it's not important. But strange anyway,.